# Random string avoiding words in array behaving incorrectly

Tags: php, arrays, random

I found some unexpected behavior in my code, so made two examples to demonstrate what was happening and couldn't figure things out from there. What I found was odd to me, and perhaps I'm missing something.

**Goal: Create a random string and avoid anything specified in an array.**

In the examples below, I have two methods of testing this.

First I have a function that creates a random string from specified characters ($characters) and then I have an array ($avoid) (here with double letters specified) which then loops and informs you if the code worked and it indeed found what was specified in the array.

This seems to work, however then I modified the second function to attempt to generate a new random string if the same trigger happened. This to avoid having a string with anything in the array.

This part doesn't seem to work.. I'm not sure how else to modify it from here, but I must be missing something. Running the code works, but it catches some things and misses other times.. which I wouldn't expect from code.

```
function getrandom($loopcount)
{
    $loopcount++;

    $length     = 20;
    $characters = 'abc';
    $string     = '';

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++)
        $string.= $characters[ mt_rand( 0,strlen($characters) ) ];

    $avoid = array(
                   'aa',
                   'bb',
                   'cc'
                   );

    foreach ($avoid as $word)
        if ( stripos($string,$word) )
            $string = 'Double '.$word.' Detected:'.$string;

    return '<h1 style="color:blue;">'.$string.'<h1>';
}
echo getrandom(0);
echo getrandom(0);
echo getrandom(0);



function getrandom2($loopcount)
{
    $loopcount++;

    $length     = 20;
    $characters = 'abc';
    $string     = '';

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++)
        $string.= $characters[ mt_rand( 0,strlen($characters) ) ];

    $avoid = array(
                   'aa',
                   'bb',
                   'cc'
                   );

    foreach ($avoid as $word)
        if ( stripos($string,$word) )
            $string = getrandom2($loopcount);

    return '<h1 style="color:green;">'.$string.'<h1>';
}
echo getrandom2(0);
echo getrandom2(0);
echo getrandom2(0);
```

Comment: `stripos` should be checked like this: `if (false !== stripos($string, $word))`

Answer (score 1):

I used this one

```
function randomToken($length) 
{
    srand(date("s"));
    $possible_charactors = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $string = "";
    while(strlen($string)<$length) 
    {
        $string .= substr($possible_charactors, rand()%strlen($possible_charactors),1);
    }
    return($string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `stripos()` with a tripple operator, otherwise your if will interpret the occurrence  at position 0 as false (1)

```
foreach ($avoid as $word){
    if ( stripos($string,$word) !== FALSE){
        $string = getrandom2($loopcount);
    }
}
```

(1) http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
print gen_rand_str_avoid('abc', 20, array('aa', 'bb', 'cc'));

function gen_rand_str($chars, $length) {
  $str = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $str .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
  }
  return $str;
}

function gen_rand_str_avoid($chars, $length, array $avoids) {
  while (true) {
    $str = gen_rand_str($chars, $length);
    foreach ($avoids as $avoid) {
      if (stripos($str, $avoid) !== false) {
        continue 2;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
  return $str;
}
```